# Как получить кодировку страницы на NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, парсер

Вопрос прост - как получить кодировку страницы?

Значение атрибута meta charset может быть не указано, а решение нужно универсальное.

На w3c подглядел, что стандартное значение тоже может отличаться:

"In HTML 4: ISO-8859-1;

In HTML5: Unicode UTF-8;

In Windows: ANSI(Windows-1252)"

Есть ли какой то универсальный способ получить кодировку страницы или, может определить ее?

---

P.s.
Модули принимаются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете попробовать [этот модуль](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-character-encoding).

Comment: За модуль благодарен)
Это открывает путь к варианту:

1.Проверить charset - взять кодировку оттуда
2.Если нет - Проверить кодировку модулем.

В теории шансы пролететь мимо малы)

Comment: Оставлю этот ответ как правильный,за неимением лучших вариантов,но написать таки решил с вот этим модулем :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/charset